# Javascript regular expression to match "123" out of test123

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript:

I have a sentence "this is a test123" and i need to match the group of numbers following the word test.

Is there a way to do this other than with using groups?

This is what i got, but i'd like to make this work without using a group (if possible)

```
var str = str.match(/test.([0-9]{1,3})/)
```

Basically i just need to say "any number group preceded by 'test'"

Comment: Can you explain why you'd like to do it without using groups, so that we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: why does it matter if they come back in groups?

Comment: was hoping to keep it simple / single line of code.

Comment: Using groups is really the most straightforward way to go about this

Comment: [0-9][0-9]?[0-9]? ...?? How long is the number expected to be? Great thing about RegEx is there's always more than one way to skin a cat. :-)

Comment: You can also use `str.split("test")[1] //123`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple single line of code (yet groups, but simple):

```
"this is a test123".replace(/.*test(\d{1,3}).*/, "$1");  // "123"
```

Or another version with `match`:

```
("this is a test123".match(/test(\d{1,3})/) || []).pop();  // "123"
```

And one more single line without regex:

```
parseInt("this is a test123".split("test")[1], 10);  // 123
```

Comment: The last example only works if there are no more <s>characters</s> digits after it.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, not characters but exactly *digits*, i.e. if the match should contain three digits and no more.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the groups you could do it with 2 simple functions on one line:

```
 str = str.match(/test[0-9]{1,3}/).toString().replace('test', '');
```